# java - Jnlp Could not parse launch file. Error at line 0

Tags: java, jnlp, java-web-start

The JNLP fails to launch and gives the error "Could not parse launch file. Error at line 0."

Here is the file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://192.168.102.95:8080/aasweb/" href="PdaSynch.jsp">
    <information>
        <title>Pda Synch</title>
        <vendor>Amplex</vendor>
        <homepage href="http://192.168.102.95:8080/" />
        <description>Pda Synch</description>
    </information>
    <security>
        <all-permissions/>
    </security>
    <resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" />
        <jar href="PdaSynch.jar" />
    </resources>

    <application-desc main-class="com.amplex.pda.ProcessPDAFiles" name="pdaSynch">
        <argument>user12</argument>
    </application-desc>
</jnlp>
```

Comment: It appears valid to me, but try validating it with [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/).

Comment: ..Stop sabotaging my edits!

Comment: I tried it with JaNeLA and get the following message: Content type content/unknown does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
The processing instruction target matching "[xX][mM][lL]" is not allowed.

Comment: Are you testing the version coming form the server, or the one directly off the file-system?  The content type should be supplied by the server.

Comment: testing it from the server got me the following message: Content type application/x-java-jnlp-file;charset=UTF-8 does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
Premature end of file.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is fix the server to return the correct type for a JNLP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it, I removed href="PdaSynch.jsp" attribute from jnlp tag